# Estimate for derivative of harmonic function

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

I'm having trouble understanding the proof of the following proposition:

> **Proposition**
> Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and $u$ be harmonic on $U$. Then for every $\bar{u}\in U$ and $r>0$ such that $\overline{B(\bar{x},r)}\subset U$ it follows that
> $$|u_{x_i}(\bar{u})|\leq\frac{n}{r}\sup_{y\in\partial B(\bar{x},r)}|u(y)|.$$

Then the proof does this:
$u$ is harmonic, thus $u_{x_i}$ is harmonic. Now using the mean-value property gives
$$u_{x_i}=\mathrel{\int\!\!\!\!\!\!-}_{B(x,r)}u_{x_i}(\bar{x})\,dS(\bar{x})=\frac{1}{\alpha(n)r^n}\int_{B(x,r)}u_{x_i}\,d\bar{x}$$
Using Gauss-Green theorem we get
$$\frac{1}{\alpha(n)r^n}\int_{\partial B(x,r)}u(\bar{x})\nu^i\,dS(\bar{x})\leq\frac{1}{\alpha(n)r^n}\cdot\sup_{y\in\partial B(x,r)}|u(y)|\cdot n\alpha(n)r^{n-1}=\frac{n}{r}\sup_{y\in\partial B(x,r)}|u(y)|.$$

The step I don't get is the step with the inequality, where does the supremum come from? I do get that in this step the mean-value property is again used, which yiels the last term, but can we just apply the mean-value property to $u\nu^i$, i.e. $\int_{\partial B(x,r)}u(\bar{x})\nu^i\,dS(\bar{x})=u(\bar{x})\nu^i$? (I don't think so, but what else could've been used here?)

Comment: An integral can always be bounded by the sup of the function over the domain of integration times the size of the domain. This fact combined with the fact that $\nu$ is a unit vector yields the result. For example, $| \int_a^b f(x) dx |\leq |b-a|\sup_{x\in[a,b]} |f(x)|$ and similarly for surface or volume integrals.

Comment: Ah yea, now I see it like that it makes sense, thank you. I only don't get where the unit vector comes in play, could you elaborate that for me?

Comment: $\sup |u\nu^i|\leq \sup |u|$ since $|\nu^i|\leq 1$

Comment: Ah yes of course, thanks a lot! Want to post it as an answer?